# WIndows PowerShell provisioning script not being executed

Tags: windows, powershell, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm deploying a Windows 2012 R2 VSI and need to be able to manage it using Ansible.

I'm using this Ansible sample script [ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1) although renamed and have the script hosted on SL Object storage. I specify a postinstall script URL including `https` (which is supposed to cause the execution of the script after downloading) during the order.

After the Windows VSI is ready I attempt to run a `win-ping` as follows:

`- name: ad1 ready
  gather_facts: false
  tags: setup
  hosts: ad1
  tasks:
    - name: ping the windows vsi
      win_ping:`

This fails with the output:

`fatal: [169.55.189.16]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='169.55.189.16', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x107c0b310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))", "unreachable": true}`

If I connect to the system and look in `c:\PostInstall` I see my script has been downloaded. If I then open a PowerShell and run the script, I am able to then run the above `win-ping` successfully.

This tells me that the script is downloaded cleanly and is apparently correct, but is *not* being executed in spite of the `https` in the postinstall URL.

I can't find any documentation on requirements of the postinstall script for windows, but I'm wondering if the problem is that I'm using a PowerShell script, and that the post provision process tries to run this in a standard CMD shell.

Does anyone have any ideas or thoughts on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with powershell succesfully, you should be able to see the logs of the powershell execution in "C:\postInstallScript.log" perhaps it contains more information about the error.

Anyway if you are still facing this issue I suggest you to open a ticket in Softlayer with "hardware issue" subject, because the issue is likely due to a restriction in the windows machine which is not allowing to execute the script.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! I don't have C:\postInstallScript.log but am opening a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with PowerShell as a provisioning script is the default configuration of PowerShell requires a signed PowerShell script to execute (with no arguments defined).  If the PowerShell script is not signed, the execution policy has to be changed on the server, or flags passed to the PowerShell interpreter to allow execution.